# ANT+ and UPSM (ultra power saving mode)

Tags: samsung, bluetooth, battery-saver

I have a Samsung device with ANT+ support and i would like to connect to ANT+ devices when in UPS(ultra power saving) mode.

However, in UPS mode with bluetooth enabled, the ANT+ is not working.

Whereas in normal mode ANT+ works when Bluetooth is enabled.

Note that: ANT+ uses the same range of frequencies than WIFI and Bluetooth 4

Some specific details:
ANT HAL service: 3.0.0

ANT Radio service: 4.16.00

ANT+ Plugins 3.6.40

(I can't tag it as 'ant+')

Comment: As the developer of an ANT+ app my first advice is to switch this stuff off when stuff is not working which sorts out half of my support issues.  I suspect there is no way to control this unless Samsung have some back-doors into there power saving control.  What is your use case needing this ultra low power mode?

Comment: @Ifor I use for the practise of long term outdoor sports, the saving power mode is a superb function. It enables me to do GPS tracking and check maps for much longer time than in normal mode. And through BLE i can be connected to a BLE sensor but i can't with my good ANT+ sensor. From UPSM I can open/use any installed app but as ANT is a service/ driver I can't.

Comment: You must be doing some proper long sessions.  A reasonable modern device should be able to do 5-6 hours without anything specials needed.  If you can go screen off most of the time your looking to double this.  Do you know what the runtime difference is your seeing with this mode?  I am well aware of the desire to stick with ANT+ it is far far better stability wise.

Comment: From my experience when I am using UPS mode the battery last not less than 3times more.  Also it avoids the battery draining caused by some services and background apps. I assume that comparing with normal mode in a device with few installed apps the difference will be smaller.

Comment: It will be easer to use a bigger power bank instead of investigating mutual influence of radio technologies.

Comment: IMO a powerbank is a workaround based in brute force and I would prefer to find out to improve performance for the out of the box hardware. And in android devices there is a lot of margin for performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

**ANT+ functions are not loaded during Samsung ultra saving mode (UPSM).**

For non-rooted users has not impact has Samsung  doesn't include any system app that uses ANT+ protocol.

For rooted users, they can manage the system apps, so they can enable ANT apps to be used during UPSM.

Workarounds:

- Using Normal saving mode and ANT
  or
- UPSM with BLE apps and BLE sensors